# cusp model in R

Tags: r, linear

I have run a cusp model in R. Although the cusp model showed good fit and moreover the pseudo-R square is 0.86, the AIC of the linear model is lower (69.55 for linear while 98.54 for cusp). However, the R-square of the linear is only 0.09.

In this case is the presence of cusp justified? Can we say that non-linearity may be present in the system or the linear model is better (in terms of AIC)?